# slow graphics when cpu usage is high in 14.04

Tags: unity, ati, graphics, 14.04

I just upgraded to 14.04 and it has an annoying issue to me.  Whenever it is doing something CPU intensive (ie. encoding audio or video and the usage is over 80%) Unity goes veeerrry slowly.  Windows don't update smoothly, cursors blink erratically, maximizing and minimizing windows are choppy, etc.  I have a quad core i7 processor and AMD Raedon R9 270 graphics card with the latest linux drivers installed.  Is Unity not using the graphics card, and doing everything in CPU for some reason?  Previously Unity seemed to handle web browsing, e-mail, etc. fine while under high CPU usage while encoding video in 12.04 and 12.10, but it seems unusable right now.

Any thoughts?